nginx + php-fpm + rdkafka = SIGSEGV (mac m1)
I’m facing a very strange issue that I can’t seem to understand or resolve.
Here’s the setup:

MacOS Sonoma (M1)
Tried different versions and configurations of Nginx
PHP 8.2/8.3/8.4 (the issue occurs on all of them)
PHP rdkafka (tested with this repository as well as versions built from PECL)
librdkafka 2.5.0 (installed via brew)

Here’s a simple script:
<?php

$conf = new \RdKafka\Conf();
$conf->set('bootstrap.servers', 'kafka:9092');
$producer = new \RdKafka\Producer($conf);

When I run this script from the command line, it works fine. However, when I run it through PHP-FPM, I get a SIGSEGV (segmentation fault).
The script failed on create \RdKafka\Producer
I've tried to debug with lldb, but no luck
Any ideas or suggestions?
